# Spring boot taglibs

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-boot

При добавлении строки:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

index.jsp страница открывается в браузере как текст с исходным кодом. Как мне это исправить?

index.jsp

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/main.css"/>
    <title>Server API</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="detailsForm">
        <input type="text" hidden="hidden" id="id" name="id">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-3">Введите имя</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="control-label col-xs-3">Введите email</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone" class="control-label col-xs-3">Введите телефон</label>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-9">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="save()">Сохранить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.1.1-1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>server_api</groupId>
    <artifactId>server_api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--DB-->
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1211</postgresql.version>

        <webjars-jquery.version>3.1.1-1</webjars-jquery.version>
        <webjars-bootstrap.version>3.3.7</webjars-bootstrap.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-bootstrap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${webjars-jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**В общем решение было убрать**  `<scope>provided</scope>`

Answer (score 0):

Самой первой строкой

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
```

Comment: не помогло, результат без изменений